# How to use the same database and cursor through the whole app properly?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, global-variables

I have huge databases (~ 40K rows) which I deal with in my app. There is one activity which has a list view that uses a CursorAdaptor to display and search in the whole database rows. Each time the user deals with a database, I open the database and create the required Cursor and I call Cursor.getCount() in another thread to tackle the laziness issue of cursors and make it fully ready for future operations. It takes around 7 seconds to have Cursor.getCount() done for the huge databases.

Users may invoke this activity multiple times so I store the cursor in a global class as a static data member and I always reuse the same cursor.

I guess that if I did not close the cursor and the database properly I may get weird results. Right?!

My question is: When I should close the cursor and the database?

It will not be possible to close the database and the cursor in Activity.onStop() since I will have to re-open the database and the cursor each time the activity goes from being invisible to visible. And if I did the close in Activity.onDestroy, then the app might be killed by the OS (when device's available memory is low) before the onDestroy is called.

Comment: "Getting" the cursor is a relatively fast operation, no?

Comment: Yes, @pst, to just get the cursor is so fast but the first interaction between the adapter and the cursor takes long time (depending on the cursor results size). That's why I explicitly call `Cursor.gerCount()` in another thread with a progress bar in the main thread to make any interactions afterwards with the cursor pretty fast.

Comment: 40K rows is not huge. It's TINY!!!!

Comment: @MitchWheat well this is relative :) anyway, it takes ~ 7 seconds when the cursor is first used. I have this delay occurs only once when the user selects the database (with a progress bar of-course). And it will not be possible to make the user wait for the 7 seconds each time the activity is selected. That't why I store the cursor globally.

Comment: @AshrafSousa Why is a cursor needed just for a "COUNT"? And *why is it so slow*? (Does it fetch each record?) Can the operation be paginated or written to take advantage of SQL? (That is, it sounds like a solution to the wrong problem.)

Comment: No, @pst. I need the cursor to be passed to the adapter (used by the list view).

Comment: So the user is going to be able (or forced) to process/visualize 40k entries at a time?

Comment: @pst: why does it always amount to that question?!?  ;)

Comment: @MitchWheat Got off on a tangent! :(

Comment: Umm.. actually I show them in the list view so the user can scroll the records. I agree with you @pst , the list is practically too long for the user to scroll. That's why I provide a search capability which works nice with the same list view. I can limit the rows shown initially in the list view to say 5K.. but in this case the user can search in the list and find recods which are not shown by default in the list view. Umm.. do you think, this is ok from usability point of view?

Comment: Look up different "pagination" (keyword) techniques that can be used for a "virtual list". The idea is to push the work off to the SQLite engine (which is good at this sort of thing) and only deal with the data in smaller chunks (pagination after initial where filters, etc).

Comment: @pst: It is a list of people names. As you propose, I may make names start with a certain alphabet character in a separate page/list but this would be a bit not intuitive for the small databases (like 100 records which I also support). I do not how well to solve this but it seems that you are pushing me to the right direction.

Comment: @pst: If I took your approach, in which method I should close the database and the cursor?

Comment: Well, for starters db connections and cursor should not be open only while querying them, your problem actually is related to how to improve sql queries and also add some data caching mechanism, maybe use some POJO with a LruCache, that's a decision you'll have to take. But trying to answer your question: You close the db and cursor after you're done querying them.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you turn this global static class into a [singleton](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html) so that you don't run into instantiation problems, which it sounds like you are referencing. Once you call getInstance() in your singleton you will always get the same cursor and DB connection within that class.

Comment: I already always get the same instance for the cursor. The question is when to close these cursor and database? because I noticed when the database is not closed properly, weird issues happen!